# Difference between RouteCollection.Ignore and RouteCollection.IgnoreRoute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, ignoreroute

What's the difference between `RouteCollection.Ignore(url, constraints)` and `RouteCollection.IgnoreRoute(url, constraints)`?

#### Background

New MVC projects include this `IgnoreRoute` call in Global.asax `RegisterRoutes` method to skip routing for requests to .axd locations that are handled elsewhere in the ASP.NET system.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

I wanted to add an additional ignored route to a project and I started to type out the new line. After `routes.I`, Intellisense pops up with `.Ignore` and `.IgnoreRoute`, both sounding about the same.

According to the MSDN docs, you can see that one is an instance method of the `System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection` class and the other is an extension method on that class from `System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions`.

- `RouteCollection.Ignore`: "Defines a URL pattern that should not be checked for matches against routes if a request URL meets the specified constraints" ([MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992982.aspx)).
- `RouteCollection.IgnoreRoute`: "Ignores the specified URL route for the given list of the available routes and a list of constraints" ([MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470170.aspx)).

Both take a route URL pattern and a set of constraints restricting the application of the route on that URL pattern.

Answer (score 20):

Between the [source for `System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions` on CodePlex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/44b53cd4dd84#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fRouteCollectionExtensions.cs) and running a little [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) on my local GAC for `System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection`, it doesn't appear there is a difference, though they seem to have completely independent code to do the same thing.

#### `RouteCollection.IgnoreRoute` (via [CodePlex source](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/44b53cd4dd84#src/System.Web.Mvc/RouteCollectionExtensions.cs))

```
public static void IgnoreRoute(this RouteCollection routes, string url, object constraints) {
    if (routes == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("routes");
    }
    if (url == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
    }

    IgnoreRouteInternal route = new IgnoreRouteInternal(url) {
        Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(constraints)
    };

    routes.Add(route);
}
```

#### `RouteCollection.Ignore` (via ILSpy decompile)

```
public void Ignore(string url, object constraints) {
    if (url == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
    }
    RouteCollection.IgnoreRouteInternal item = new RouteCollection.IgnoreRouteInternal(url) {
        Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(constraints)
    };
    base.Add(item);
}
```

#### Differences

The only real difference is the obvious difference in location, one being an instance method in the `RouteCollection` class itself and one being an extensions method on that class. After you factor in the code differences that come from instance vs. extension execution (like the vital null check on the extended instance), they appear identical.

At their core, they both use the exact same `StopRoutingHandler` class. Both have their own versions of a sealed `IgnoreRouteInternal` class, but those versions are identical in code.

```
private sealed class IgnoreRouteInternal : Route {
    public IgnoreRouteInternal(string url)
        : base(url, new StopRoutingHandler()) {
    }
    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary routeValues) {
        return null;
    }
}
```